# ASP.NET ListView SelectMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I'm sorry for being ignorant about this and I can't find the answer anywhere - but I suspect it's because I do not know how to word the query.

Anyway, I have a ListView on an ASP.NET page, with a SelectMethod called "GetData".

On the page_load event, I'm retrieving a references to various labels using

```
this.Master.FindControl(....
```

This works fine, but as soon as this is called, I've noticed control suddenly jumps to my GetData method - the SelectMethod of the ListView.

This is causing me some issues since the local database is only populated AFTER I've retrieved references to various controls etc - i.e. the SelectMethod is called before I've had chance to fill the DB.

I'm fairly inexperienced (as you've guessed) with ASP, but could someone please explain why this happens. i.e. What exactly causes the SelectMethod to be called.

Thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: How are you populating the database and when is it being populated in the lifecycle? Init? Page Load? Or some other way?

Comment: The DB is being populated at the end of the Page_Load, when I have references to all the controls that will be assigned values during the load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.select(v=vs.110).aspx), the Select Method appears to be called in the PreRender phase.

The page load happens before the PreRender.

Try putting your database populating code in the page init.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but the program flow is now: